# Function pointer static, constructor

Tags: c++

In this code we have static class variable and i need someone to explain what happens here and how i can use it.It is a static class variable and a function that gets the variable with a reference.

```
class Constructor 
{
private:
static Constructor constructor;
public:
static Constructor* constructor();

};
Constructor Constructor::constructor;
Constructor* constructor::constructor()
{
    return &constructor;
}
```

Comment: Look up the singleton design pattern.

Comment: *"...a function that gets the variable with a reference."* - that's not a reference; it's a pointer. And that code isn't valid regardless as you cannot have a member variable and function (static or otherwise) with the same id.

Comment: yea I saw my mistake thank you a lot

Comment: What does "function pointer static, constructor" mean?

Answer (score 1):

Once you remove the errors so that it compiles

```
class Constructor 
{
private:
static Constructor constructor_;
public:
static Constructor* constructor();

};
Constructor Constructor::constructor_;
Constructor* Constructor::constructor()
{
    return &constructor_;
}
```

you end up with a single private instance of Constructor in the static variable `Constructor::constructor_` that can only be accessed through its static public `Constructor::constructor()` method. This type of construction which allows only the creation of a single instance of a class is called a singleton. It is used like this:

```
int main(){   
    auto* s1 = Constructor::constructor();
    auto* s2 = Constructor::constructor();

    std::cout << (s1 == s2);
}
```

See working version [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbb32f2329a2c2cd).

See [Thread-Safe Initialization of a Singleton](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/thread-safe-initialization-of-a-singleton) for additional information.